# Apache MPM event take long time for SSL init

Tags: performance, apache, ssl, apache2

My apache server take lot of time (5-10 seconds) to init SSL connection when there is some workload.

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers             2
    MinSpareThreads          25
    MaxSpareThreads          75
    ThreadLimit              64
    ThreadsPerChild          25
    MaxRequestWorkers        150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

My score board there are lot of idle workers.
[image]

UPDATE 1

When there are dots in scoreboard it work better : 20ms to init SSL connection:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I increase MaxRequestWorkers to 200 it's work better but I'm unable link that change to an apache scoreboard analyze.

Maybe I can increase more than 200.